# why grep "!" shows "bash: !: event not found"?

Tags: bash, grep, special-characters

If I run

```
grep "!" test.txt
```

it will show error

> bash: !: event not found

Well, I know I actually should use `grep '!'`. But how to understand the above error?

I know `!` is bash special character. According to http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

> Double quotes: "..." prevents some substitutions but allows others.
>   Every substitution that begins with a dollar sign $ is performed, as
>   is the legacy `...` (backtick) command substitution. Backslash
>   escaping is also performed. No word splitting or filename expansion is
>   performed.

It doesn't mention that double quotes will affect !. Could somebody explain how does bash or grep interpret `grep "!"`? What is the "event"?

Answer (score 6):

It's not `grep` that's causing it. It's your `bash` that is interpreting the `!`. Switch to a newer version of `bash` or use `single quotes '!'` to shut up `bash`.

Comment: why new version has no error? Bug or some new feature?

Comment: Actually in your scenario, `grep \!  test.txt` would work as well. I guess it's a bug that's why this changed behavior.

Comment: Ok, `grep '!'` works, Why `bash -c 'grep \'!\' test.txt'` doesn't work?

Comment: Actually you need to realize how quoting works, single quoting , that is, in your above case. You can't slip in a single quote inside of single quotes just by escaping it. Why? Coz, the backslash ain't special inside of single quotes, the way it is special inside double quotes or in empty space. You shoud do this: `bash -c 'grep '\''!'\'' test.txt'`

Comment: The History Expansion feature is still available and enabled by default as of Bash 4.4.19, and I don't expect it to be removed soon. Quote it or put `set +o histexpand` in your `.bashrc` or equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking at Bash's [History Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html) feature. Some find it handy to recall previous commands, but I just put `set +o histexpand` in my `.bashrc` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to search for part of the command.